# Drawing rectangles in php not working

Tags: php, image, drawing

I am creating an image in php and populating it with 10x10 pixel rectangles filled with a color.

```
$image = imagecreate(150,150);
$background = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0); //black background
for ($row=0; $row < 15; $row++) { 
    for ($col=0; $col < 15; $col++) { 
        $x1 = 10* $col;
        $y1 = 10*$row;
        $x2 = 10*($col + 1);
        $y2 = 10*($row + 1);

        imagefilledrectangle($image, $x1,$y1,$x2,$y2, imagecolorallocate($image, 100,100,100)); //grey rectangle
    }
}

imagepng($image, "ciph.png");
```

This works for small images no bigger than 150x150 pixels and i get a completely grey filled rectangle. but soon as i try bigger images. it only adds rectangles to part of the image. Any idea what is causing this? it appears there is a limit on the number of individual objects i can draw.

[image]

15x15

[image]

18x18

ive counted and it appears to only draw 256 rectangles... doesnt seem like a coincidence that that is 2 to the 8th power.

Any help would be much appreciated! thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in how you're creating the image.  If you change first line from:

`$image = imagecreate(150,150);`

to:

`$image = imagecreatetruecolor(150,150);`

it will allow more than 256 rectangles to be drawn to the image.

`imagecreatetruecolor()` also gives the image a black background by default, instead of the blank background that `imagecreate()` gives, so you won't need the second line as well.

Comment: You did it! Thank you so much. By any chance do you know the reason behind this error with imagecreate or is this limit just an inherent property?

Comment: I was trying to figure out why this was the case so I could include it in my answer, but I couldn't figure it out.  The PHP documentation didn't give any hints as to why, either.  Sorry!